# How do I get my <li> items to drop straight down in a drop-down menu?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I am creating a personal website for my programming class and I'm having trouble having my "li" tags items drop down, but instead their going off to the right. For example I hover over my "li" tag to have my drop down "li" items drop down. But instead they drop down and go to the right. I want them to go straight down. Any help?

Here is the CSS (And yes I know that some of my CSS is repeated and unnecessary)  :

```
#nav {
    background-color:#222;
    margin:-15px;
    margin-left:230px;
    margin-right:230px
}

#nav_wrappper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:left;
}

#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;

}

#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}

#nav ul li:hover {
    background-color:#333;
}

#nav ul li a,visited {
    color:#ccc;
    display:block;
    padding:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}

#nav ul ul {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#333;
    border: 5px solid #222;
    border-top:0;
    margin-left: -5px;
    min-width:160px;
}

#nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}

#nav ul ul li a, vistited{
    color:#ccc;
}

#nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color:#099;
}
```

Comment: Please also include your HTML. But the answer is probably to remove `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: Add `float:none` to `#nav ul ul li`. (You may also want to reset `width:auto`.)